# trouble with 2010 save as dbf

Tags: vba, excel, dbf

Below is the code I'm trying to fix. It works in Excel 2007 but not in Excel 2010.

I believe it has to do with the XlDBF4 part. Please help.

```
Range("A1").Select
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Range("SetUp!L34") & Range("SetUp!D28") & "_" & Range("SetUp!F28") & ".dbf", FileFormat:= _
    xlDBF4, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Range("Setup!L28") & Range("SetUp!D28") & "_" & Range("SetUp!F28") & " " & Range("SetUp!D30") & ".xls", FileFormat:= _
    xlNormal, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False _
    , CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message? If so, please edit your question to include it. Thank you.

Comment: If the below answer does NOT help - just use macro recorder for save as to every format you need - it'll provide you all the required code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code instead:

```
Range("A1").Select
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Range("SetUp!L34") & Range("SetUp!D28") & "_" & Range("SetUp!F28") & ".dbf", FileFormat:= _
    xlDBF4, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Range("Setup!L28") & Range("SetUp!D28") & "_" & Range("SetUp!F28") & " " & Range("SetUp!D30") & ".xls", FileFormat:= _
    xlExcel8, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False _
    , CreateBackup:=False
```

I think the case is `xlNormal`: if you want `xls` - you should use `xlExcel8` instead. It's strange your code works - there's no `xlNormal` constant at all: [XlFileFormat Enumeration (Excel)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb241279%28v=office.12%29.aspx)